# SP2010 - change width of list column, or set a max-width with CSS

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, bcs

Some of the list columns I render have the option for the user to enter a mass of data. If they do it can cause the view of the screen to be skewed as there is too much content in one column and the rest of the columns aren't visible on the screen without scrolling.

I am seeking to change the width of list columns, similar to the solution that is described here: http://aanuwizard.com/2010/08/01/sharepoint-2010-how-to-change-width-of-list-column/ but I didn't want to use sharepoint designer. Ideally I could just set a max width for everything, so it wouldn't ruin the views if a lot of content was input.

I was hoping to do it with CSS, as I can inject css into my SP pages. Is it possible? how could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very nice solution, but if you don't want to use SharePoint Designer it might be what you need:
One thing you could do if you don't want to use the SharePoint Designer is to add a Content Editor WebPart containing a javascript that applies the CSS for you.

You would either add a stylesheet in your content editor webpart and apply your stilesheet to the desired element, or you can also try to change the .style property of your element directly. As seen here:

```
function changeElement(id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.style.color = "red";
  el.style.fontSize = "15px";
  el.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
}
```

Some more information on how to do this can be found here:

http://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript